# Remove any pixels where the alpha value is not 1, compositor

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I have a render output that gives me my desired output but I want to remove the alpha channel.
I want either, the pixels that have an alpha value less than 1 to be completely transparent or completely solid.
In this picture you can see that a vertical column of blue has transparency, I want to remove this or it be solid. How can I achieve this in the compositor?
[image: Remove the pixels with alpha]

Answer (score 1):

After a while playing around I found a fix that seems a bit hacky but does a good enough job for me.

First I split the image into RGBA, then using the alpha channel I made any pixel with an alpha above 0.8 set to 1 and recombined the image.
I then used any pixel that had an alpha value below 0.8 used as a mask to cut themselves out of the image.

Here's the node setup:
[image: Sharp Alpha Fix]